# RDS still in grace period after licensing

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services

I'm really worried that my RDS infrastructure will crash in 64 days.
I have long entered the RDS license code and activated the License Server, manages user-level licenses.

From time to time, however, when I log in, I have the notification of the remaining days on the bottom right.

In addition, launching the command:

`wmic /namespace:\root\CIMV2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TerminalServiceSetting WHERE (__CLASS !="") CALL GetGracePeriodDays`

I see that there are only 64 days left.

I have also set up the GPO
Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Remote Desktop Services \ Remote Desktop Session Host \ Licensing
- Use the specified Remote Desktop license servers
- Set the Remote Desktop licensing mode

How can I be sure it's all right?

The environment is WS2016, the diagnostic tool does not detect problems.
[link diagnostico tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbTs9.png)
Also the configuration of the remote desktop license server turns out to be right.
[link rds config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xP4t.png)

Can you serve some other information?

Comment: Last time I checked, User licensing is not enforced. If the Remote Desktop Session Host is activated, it should continue to work. If it were not activated, it would log a warning in the event log, and a visible notification in the system tray. If you want to confirm the license server is working, it should be updating the msTSExpireDate attribute on user accounts when they logon, providing the license server is in the Terminal Server License Servers group.

Comment: Do your clients get licenses in the TSLIC MMC?